# Prevent AWS from killing tmux last session

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, tmux

I recently started using tmux on the aws deep learning ami , I am unable to reconnect to the detached session again. After using the magic command ctrl+b d  , when I do "tmux attach" it says "no session"

Does aws kills the session after detach or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What is `detached` instance?

Comment: @Marcin sorry is supposed to be detached session , corrected it

Comment: anyway, aws does not kill anything on your instances.

Comment: no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default  , i get this when I do tmux ls

Comment: What does `tmux ls` return?

Comment: @Marcin no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

Comment: I don't know what's happening. Must be something with your setup. Definitely tmux works on both AL2 and Ubuntu instances, as I use it myself and never had issues.

Comment: Is tmux still running? Perhaps something is removing the socket. If tmux is still running, try `pkill -USR1 tmux`.

Comment: @Marcin, So I was able to figure it out. check the answer i submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out.

Since I was connecting from Windows using Putty and cygwin to do the ssh connection, there was a Ctrl + D binding to exit the terminal.

Due to the delay in keystrokes ,the keystroke to detach in turn disconnects the the terminal (Ctrl + D).

I was able to fix by setting "`set -o ignoreeof`" in the terminal as well as setting the  a tmux config to disable it as well (from : https://github.com/ochi/dots/blob/master/.tmux.conf)

```
# prevent logout from ^D in laggy sessions
set-environment -g 'IGNOREEOF' 1
```